# I keep getting this Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: heroku-redis

I recently installed **Heroku Redis**. Until then, the app worked just fine. I am using `Bull` for queuing and `ioredis` as the redis library. I had connection issues initially but I have resolved that as I no longer get the error. However, this new Error described shows up.

Please check these details below;

**Package.json Start Script**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "sh ./run.sh"
  }
```

**run.sh** file

```
node ./app/services/queues/process.js &&
node server.js
```

From the logs on the heroku console, I see this.

1. Processing UPDATE_USER_BOOKING... Press [ctrl C] to Cancel
2. {"level":"info","message":"mongodb connected"}

**1** is my log in the `process` script. This tells me that the consumer is running and ready to process any data it receives.
**2** Tells me that mongo is connected. It can be found in my `server.js`(entry file).

My challenge is after those 2 lines, it then shows this;

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL

Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes

Process exited with status 22

State changed from starting to crashed

So, I don't know why this is happening even when I have the `PORT` sorted out already as described in their `docs`. See this for clarity:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4900, ()=>{})
```

**Note**: It was working before until I introduced the Redis bit just a day ago.

Could there be an issue with the way I am running both `server` and the `Queue process` in the `package.json file`? I have been reading answers similar to this, but they are usually focused on the `PORT` fix which is not my own issue as far as I know.

**TroubleShooting** : I removed the `queue process` from the start script and the issue was gone. I had this instead

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js -p $PORT"
  }
```

So it becomes clear that this line below;

`node ./app/services/queues/process.js` **was the issue**

Now, How then do I run this queue process script? I need it to run to listen to any `subscription` and then **run** the `processor script`. It works fine locally with the **former** start script.

**Please Note**: I am using Bull for the Queue. I followed this guide to implement it and it worked fine locally.
[Bull Redis Implementation Nodejs Guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-queues-in-node-js-8b3a06ce0dd0)

I will appreciate any help on this as I am currently blocked on my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go another way. I read up on how to run background jobs on heroku with Bull and I got a guide which I implemented. The idea is to utilize Node's concurrency API. For the guide a wrapper was used called `throng` to implement this.
I removed the `process` file and just wrapped my consumer script inside the `start` function and passed that to `throng`.

[Link to heroku guide on enabling concurrency in your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency#enabling-concurrency-in-your-app)

**Result**: I started getting `EADDR in use Error` which was because that **app.listen() is being run twice.**.
Solution: I had to wrap the `app.listen` function inside a worker and pass it to `throng` and it worked fine.
[Link to the solution to the EADDR in use Error](https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng/issues/25)

On my local Machine, I was able to push to the Queue and consume from it.  After deploying to heroku, I am not getting any errors so far.

I have tested the update on heroku and it works fine too.